# Prevent file transport from closing stream in Mule

Tags: java, file, stream, mule, transport

I'm trying to copy a `csv` file to a local directory and then parse the `SftpInputStream`. The file is copied correctly. However, although I set `streaming` to `false` in the file connector, it seems as the `file inbound-endpoint` closes the stream so that my transformer cannot parse the stream.

How can I prevent the `file:outbound-endpoint` from closing the `stream` after it has copied the file?

These are my connectors:

```
<sftp:connector name="mySftpConnector" pollingFrequency="1000" autoDelete="true" />
    <file:connector name="myFileOutputConnector" streaming="false" outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" />
```

This is my flow:

```
<flow name="myFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">

    <sftp:inbound-endpoint
            address="xxx"
            connector-ref="mySftpConnector" autoDelete="false">
            <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.csv"/>
    </sftp:inbound-endpoint>

    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/archive" connector-ref="myFileOutputConnector" />

    <transformer ref="mySftpTransformer" />

    <component>
         <spring-object bean="mySftpHandler" />
    </component>

</flow>
```

The exception thrown is:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:145)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:308)
        at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpInputStream.read(SftpInputStream.java:90)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `streaming` is not enabled on the `FTP` connector, `Mule` will attempt to read a file it picks up from the FTP server into a byte[] to be used as the payload of the MuleMessage. And stream is closed after that.

If `streaming` is used on `inbound endpoints` it is the responsability of the user to close the input stream. You can turn on the `stream` and try